# Kotlin Android- How implement CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener?

Tags: android, checkbox, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin. I created a fragment and implemented `View.OnClickListener` and `CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener`. The  `View.OnClickListener` works as expected but it shows Unresloved reference for  `CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener`.

The code is below

```
class LoginFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener, CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    override fun onClick(view: View?) {

    }


}
```

How can I implement `CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener`..?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your code that's showing the error.

Comment: Show your code ...

Answer (score 74):

Use CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener like:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
  Toast.makeText(this,isChecked.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

where `checkBox` is CheckBox ID.

Answer (score 17):

```
var checkBox:CheckBox = CheckBox(context)
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->  
        if (isChecked) {
                //Do Whatever you want in isChecked
        }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

In `Kotlin`, you can use `CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener` like:-

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
   Toast.makeText(this,isChecked.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`CheckBox.OnClickListener` is not an existing interface. [`CheckBox`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html) inherits from [`View`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), and so to assign a listener to a `CheckBox`, you can use its [`setOnClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) method, which takes an instance of [`View.OnClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html).

If you want to handle both of those events in the same `Fragment`, you'll have to differentiate the `CheckBox` and the other `View` using the parameter of the `onClick` method.

Alternatively, you could use lambdas as the listeners for your `View`s instead of the `Fragment` itself.

```
checkbox.setOnClickListener { view ->
    // handle clicks here
}
```

Using [`setOnCheckedChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener)) as mentioned in the other answers is also an option with `CheckBox`.

Comment: Perfect! I just used like:

`myCheckBox.setOnClickListener { view ->
                if (view is CheckBox) {
                    if (view.isChecked)
                        onCheck(true)
                    else
                        onCheck(false)
                }
            } `

Answer (score 1):

The easies way to use CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener for Kotlin Android like:

```
checkbox.setOnClickListener { view ->
if ((view as CheckBox).isChecked) {
    // Perform action when the checkbox is checked
} else {
    // Perform action when the checkbox is not checked
}
}
```

Hopefully this example of a code snippet can make it easier to understand the use of CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener